# Error when using 2 collections schema in single file in Mongoose MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am having myschema.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 // User Collection Schema
var RegSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    UserName: String,
    UserEmail: String,
    userprofileImage : String,
    userId: {type : String, index : true, unique: true},
    reg_time : {
        type : Date, default: Date.now
    }
}, { collection: 'user' });

 var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    PostId: {type : String, index : true, unique: true},
    PostTitle: String,
    PostContent: String,
    Userid : String,
    Likes : Array, // will get userid in this column
    post_reg_time : {
        type : Date, default: Date.now
    }
}, { collection: 'post' });

// Model
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserReg', RegSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('PostSave', PostSchema);
//exports.UserReg = UserReg;
```

i am getting Error 
    {Mongo Error: '$set' is empty You must specify a field like so{:..}}

Now if i remove Postschema collection code then it works. This schema file is used in user insertion. File code of user insertion  is

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 



var UserReg = require('./myschema.js');

module.exports = function(userdetail, callback){
var bb;

                  var UserAdd = new UserReg({
                                "UserName": userdetail.username,
                                "UserEmail": userdetail.useremail,
                                "userId": userdetail.userId,
                             "userprofileImage": userdetail.userprofileImage
                            });

                    var userdetailchange = {
                                "UserName": userdetail.username,
                                "UserEmail": userdetail.useremail,
                                "userId": userdetail.userId,
                        "userprofileImage": userdetail.userprofileImage
                    };
                    // Update if found otherwise Insert
                    UserReg.update({"userId":userdetail.userId },{ $set:userdetailchange},{upsert:true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}, function (err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err);
                            } 
                                callback("data Inserted or Updated successfully"+ JSON.stringify(data));                                
                    });

};
```

But i don't have any data right now for post collection. Once the Post collection is working without any error, i will insert the data. Any help in fixing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `module.exports`, so only the last schema (`PostSave`) is being exported.

In **myschema.js**, you can do this at the end:

```
exports.UserReg = mongoose.model('UserReg', RegSchema);
exports.PostSave = mongoose.model('PostSave', PostSchema);
```

In the other script, you can import `UserReg` with:

```
var UserReg = require('./myschema.js').UserReg;
```

Likewise, you can import `PostSave`with:

```
var PostSave = require('./myschema.js').PostSave;
```